# Detecting the difference between tabs?

Tags: c++, parsing

How do you differentiate between a one space tab and one that takes up a whole line while parsing a text file in c++ without using regex?

Comment: This question needs to be a lot more descriptive I don't have a clue what you are talking about, how about showing us the code you have so far?

Comment: A tab can be as big as you want it to be... 4 spaces, 1 space, 8 spaces, an entire line, respecting tab stops...

Comment: A "tab that takes a whole line"? Are you asking about the difference between `\t` and `\n` by any chance? I don't exactly follow what you're asking.

Comment: With "tab that takes a whole line", are you talking about a line that contains nothing but a tab?

Comment: i am parsing a text file, one line has leading space that is a tab and on another line the whole line is a horizontal tab. how would i detect the diferrence in code?

Comment: @gabe yes i am cleaning a text file and then doing a word count the tab that needs be counted takes up the whole line and the one space tab does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would store the line/string in a variable until you hit an \n. You would then, check if the string is equal, or even just contains, a single tab or, other chars also.
That would be a good way, I think. I don't know how hard this would be in C++, but I don't think it'd be too hard.

If this isn't what your looking for, I'd try restating your question... Be more clear on what your objective, or goal, is.

Comment: So...What do you want to do? Again, if all you want to do is check if the string is a single/multiple tab, all you do is check if the string is full of spaces, because tabs aren't literal characters. Please try to explain what you're doing better.

Comment: It might also help if you give us your code. Or just a snippet, the section in withwhich you are doing the parsing.

Comment: Alright! Good sauce, man, good sauce. Hope this method works out ^_^